# how to use openrowset to execute a stored procedure with parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, openrowset

I'm creating a stored procedure which gets some parameters and in turn these parameters are sent to another stored procedure which I'm calling from openrowset but I'm getting some syntax errors.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdatePrevFYConfigData 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

        @startDate datetime,
        @endDate datetime,
        @productGroup varchar(8000) = 'All',
        @projectType varchar(500) = 'All',
        @businessUnit nvarchar(50) = 'All',
        @developmentLocation nvarchar(100) = 'All'
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @start varchar(50)
declare @end varchar(50) 

set @start = cast(@startDate as varchar(40))
set @end = cast(@endDate as varchar(40))

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
select round(avg(a.DeviationDeadline),2) as DeviationDeadline, 
       round(avg(a.DeviationDefinition),2) as DeviationDefinition,
       round(avg(a.DeviationRDCosts),2) as DeviationRDCosts,
       round(avg(a.FunctionsAdded) + avg(a.FunctionsDeleted),2) as NotRealizedFuncs, 
       round(avg(a.DeviationPM2000Aufwand),2) as DeviationPM200Aufwand,
       round(avg(b.Defect),2) as Defect
       into #tempTable 
from openrowset('SQLNCLI', 
                'Server=.\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=yes;',  
                'SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC [BSC_DB].dbo.SelectScorecardGraphData
                    '''+@start+''',
                    '''+@end+''',
                    '''+@productGroup+''',
                    '''+@projectType+''',
                    ''1'',
                    ''0'',
                    ''All'',
                    ''Current'',
                    '''+@businessUnit+''',
                    '''+@developmentLocation+'''
                ') as a,

    openrowset('SQLNCLI', 'Server=.\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=yes;',  'SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC [BSC_DB].dbo.GetSPCDefectDistributionData
'''+cast(@startDate as varchar(40))+''',
'''+cast(@endDate as varchar(40))+''',
''Defect'',
'''+@projectType+''',
'''+@productGroup+''',
'''+@businessUnit+''',
'''+@developmentLocation+'''') as b


update dbo.EA_ProcessScorecard_Config_Tbl
set EPC_Deviation = case EPC_Metric
    when 'PM200' then (select  DeviationDefinition from #tempTable)
    when 'PM300' then (select  DeviationDeadline from #tempTable)
    when 'Cost'  then (select  DeviationRDCosts from #tempTable)
    when 'PM150' then (select  DeviationPM200Aufwand from #tempTable)
    when 'Defect' then (select Defect from #tempTable)
    when 'Funcs' then (select NotRealizedFuncs from #tempTable)
END
where EPC_Description = 'PrevFY' and EPC_FYYear = '0'

drop table #tempTable

END 

GO
```

I'm not able to create it and I get the error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdatePrevFYConfigData, 
Line 38 Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

... but if I use hard coded values for the parameters it works!!

Please help!

Answer (score 10):

Both OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE should be used only for accessing external data for, let's say, quick and dirty solutions, or when it is not possible to configure a permanent linked server. These functions do not provide all of the functionality available from a linked server.
The arguments of OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE do not support variables. They have to be specified as string-literal. If variables need to be passed in as arguments to these functions, a query string containing these variables can be constructed dynamically and executed using the EXEC statement.
Similar to (not syntax checked)

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',''server=.\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=yes'',''SET NOCOUNT ON;SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC [BSC_DB].dbo.SelectScorecardGraphData ''''' + cast(@param1 as varchar(10)) + ''''',''' + cast(@param2 as varchar(n)) ''')'
EXEC @sqlCommand
```

And so on...
Hope that helps. Kind regards,
Stefan

Comment: No use if the point of using OPENROWSET to call a stored proc was to put the results into a SELECT statement. I guess it simply cannot be done and the stored proc being called needs to be changed into a function. This is the solution I ended up settling on.

Answer (score 5):

```
    -- FOR USING OPENROWSETS
    EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'
        ,1

    RECONFIGURE

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #TABLESIZESYEAR SELECT NULL AS [TABLE NAME], * FROM OPENROWSET 
                    (''SQLOLEDB'',''Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'',''set fmtonly off EXEC one.[dbo].[InvestigateDataGrowthByYearAndClient] @pDATECOLUMN =' + @YEARCOLUMN + ' ,
                        @pTABLENAME = ' + @TABLENAME + ' WITH RESULT SETS(
                        ([YEAR NAME] NVARCHAR(5) NULL
                                , [NUMBER OF ROWS] CHAR(11)    
                                , [RESERVED SPACE] VARCHAR(18) 
                                , [DATA SPACE] VARCHAR(18)    
                                , [INDEX SIZE] VARCHAR(18)    
                                , [UNUSED SPACE] VARCHAR(18) )
                    )
                        ;'') '

    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500) = '@pDATECOLUMN NVARCHAR(20)
                            ,@YEARCOLUMN NVARCHAR(20)
                            ,@pTABLENAME NVARCHAR(60)';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
        ,@ParmDefinition
        ,@YEARCOLUMN = @YEARCOLUMN
        ,@pDATECOLUMN = @YEARCOLUMN
        ,@pTABLENAME = @TABLENAME
```