# SQL Server SELECT INTO Using OPENROWSET With Variables?

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table where I want to store the results of a stored procedure. To execute the stored procedure, I need to use variable values for the Database name, Database Server, and Stored Procedure name that are stored in a table. I need to work out how to write the SELECT * INTO using the OPENROWSET with my variables. This is what I have so far but there are syntax errors:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpAccountsRetrieved 
    FROM OPENROWSET(@TempDbName, 'Server=' + @TempDbServer + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC ' + @TempStoredProcName)
```

I'm pretty rusty on SQL so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide the syntax errors that you encountered. Also not sure what you are passing in for **`@TempDbName`**, as per `OPENROWSET` it should be `provider name`. Also you cannot use expressions in `OPENROWSET`.Try creating a dynamic sql to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put these configurations in place before using openRowset:

```
   -- FOR USING OPENROWSETS
        EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries'
            ,1
        RECONFIGURE
```

I think your syntax is correct.
So just Try to Go through this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292745/how-to-use-openrowset-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-with-parameters/30373567#30373567) for more help

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.